# NIMax can communicate with Keysight E36106B but pyvisa locks up forever

Tags: scpi

My code is successfully communicating with lots of test equipment but for some reason it's hanging up indefinitely when communicating with a Keysight E36106B DC supply.

The attached pictures show me getting a response to the *IDN? command through NiMAX:
[image: config1]

[image: config2]

[image: *idn? response]

For some reason this code doesn't only fail to get the *IDN? response, it hanging indefinitely even though I set the pyvisa timeout to 2s:

> ```
> def __init__(self, ip_address, timeout = 2000, debug: bool = DEBUG):
> ```

```
    self.debug = debug

    # Open Resource Manager
    rm = pyvisa.ResourceManager()
    # resources = rm.list_resources()

    visa_address = "TCPIP0::" + ip_address + "::inst0::INSTR"
    self.ps = rm.open_resource(visa_address, send_end=True)
    self.ps.timeout = timeout

    self._write("*RST") # Reset the instrument

    response = self._query("*IDN?")
    response_split = response.split(',')
    self.ps_id = {'manufacturer': response_split[0], 'model': response_split[1], "serial_number": response_split[2], 'firmware_revision': response_split[3]}
```

Any help would be very much appreciated. The same code is working with ~25 other pieces of test equipment, including another DC supply, but I need the rise time of which the E36106B is capable.